# Scala nested for loop over Streams

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, iteration

I've written the following Scala code to compute a distance matrix:

```
def dist(fasta: Stream[FastaRecord], f: (FastaRecord, FastaRecord) => Int) = {
  val inF = fasta.par
  for (i <- inF; j <- inF)
   yield (f(i, j))
}
```

This code works great in the sense that I get excellent parallelism. Unfortunately, I'm doing twice as much work as I need to as f(i, j) is the same as f(j, i). What I want to do is start j at i+1 in the stream. I can do this with indices:

```
for (i <- 0 until inF.length - 1; j <- i+1 until inF.length) 
  yield(f(inF(i), inF(j)))
```

However, asking for inF.length I've heard is not good on a Stream and this doesn't give me the parallelism.

I think there should be a way to do this iteration, however, I haven't come up with anything yet.

thanks! jim

Comment: Streams cache their results, like in [this example of fibonacci calculations](http://www.derekwyatt.org/2011/07/29/understanding-scala-streams-through-fibonacci/). So after the first time `j` traverses the whole stream it should be as quick as a normal list. Meaning I think you're better off evaluating your stream with a `length` in the beginning, and then doing only half the number of parallel calculations with your `f` function. I'm commenting this just so you understand the performance of Streams __after__ they have been iterated over once.

Comment: I think the bigger problem here is that Streams aren't optimized for random access, so the `inF(i)` and `inF(j)` operations will be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `zipWithIndex` might get you what you're looking for:

```
def dist(fasta: Stream[FastaRecord], f: (FastaRecord, FastaRecord) => Int) = {
  val inF = fasta.zipWithIndex.par
  for ((x, i) <- inF; (y, j) <- inF; if i <= j)
   yield f(x, y)
}
```

By filtering `i <= j` you can eliminate the repeated (mirrored) cases. However, I do get a warning when I compile this:

```
warning: `withFilter' method does not yet exist on scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[(FastaRecord, Int)], using `filter' method instead
```

I don't think that would really be an issue, but I also don't know how to supress the error...